# issues with booting android in our own simulation environment

Tags: android, linux, simulation, boot

We have been facing issues with booting android 5.0 to GUI in our simulation environment.

2. We have been able to successfully boot it on QEMU with our kernel image and rootfs.
3. In our sw only environment there is an issue of rootfs not able to go higher than 400 MB so by removing some of the unneeded stuff we have brought it down to 400mb
4. In our environment we pack system.img , userdata.img and cache.img into one package and provide it as rootfs. kernel and ramdisk are provided as is.
5. We were able to boot kitkat on the above simulation environment.
6. I am going to attach log below. What we see is lot of binder transation failures after surface flinger is loaded. We can see android logo but no gui after that.
7. What we are suspecting is the following either issue with selinux(we have set se linux to permissive in kernel command line.) or issue with recognising userdata.img and cache.img by init.

Any pointers to the potential issue here would be really helpful. I am new to android booting mechanisms although i have surpassable knowledge of driver development.

Attaching a link to the logs: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/im33ikwo6zvjobw70zl46/fsim_swonly.log?dl=0&oref=e&r=AAUTkq0XmQwwdsnOGAUqodCFdVHzt-2ejEstlhF40PWkNA4tjglBxO-WCtWxdRJK4GjXXemYenvq9_m9BtkEPLsDDvtw1r7qjRGDTlor5NU0EvLorixw6NgytVfYJa7FfBBpXU574_QnbbNRdjhFcM9NZRcYO0fCYmbuPllHKBbrzS8yFJWoKk3A_2D27BSXpco&sm=1

Comment: Currently suspecting issues with surfaceflinger as surfaceflinger is not able to call setpowermode call. In qemu we see setpowermode to 2 being called with the same set if images!!

Comment: Can Anyone Help on this?